# design a app in salesforce with data modelling

Tags: data-model

I am new to crm , so i don't know how to use data modelling.
I need a tutorial with some example of app development.
Can you suggest a good tutorial with sample app designing in salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Salesforce Trailhead? - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/

This specific link is a Data Modelling trailhead module from Salesforce - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_admin_beginner/modules/data_modeling

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look the following ...

For schema related stuff there is a trailhead on schema builder and viewing data model
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/data_modeling/units/schema_builder

There is also a trailhead on CRM basics

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/getting_started_crm_basics

Answer (score 0):

For deep-dive information, a few other places I always go back to -

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/data_model.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/11/enterprise-data-architecture.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5t6XBBf3ew